# Reputation in profile tab doesn't match with actual change

Tags: bug, profile-page

I noticed this for me strange behaviour on my profile page.

The "Reputation" tab says that my score has been changed by `-2`, but when clicking it, it shows that I actually got a `+2` score.

See the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I've noticed something similar. 
After waiting 5-10 minutes, everything adds up properly. I'm not sure why the solution is a function of time.